# JS: remove end of string after nth character of type

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a script to remove the end of a string after a user inserts a number of special characters.

An example would be: Remove the end of a string from the 3rd comma, including the 3rd comma, so:

```
// Hi, this, sentence, has, a, lot, of commas
```

would become:

```
// Hi, this, sentence
```

I haven't been able to accomplish this with indexOf() because I don't know where the 3rd comma will occur in the sentence and I don't want to use split because that would create a break at every comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)/[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)/[`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get the desired part of the string:

```js
const str = "Hi, this, sentence, has, a, lot, of commas";
const parts = str.split(",");
const firstThree = parts.slice(0,3);
const result = firstThree.join(",");

console.log(result, parts, firstThree);
```

In a one-liner, that would be:

```
const result = str.split(",").slice(0,3).join(",");
```

---

Another simple option would be a regex:

```js
const str = "Hi, this, sentence, has, a, lot, of commas";
const match = str.match(/([^,]+,){3}/)[0]; // "Hi, this, sentence,"
console.log(match.slice(0, -1));
```

This one uses the string variant of [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

This is how the regex works:

- In a capturing group `()`,
- Find me at least one (`+`) character that is not a comma (`[^,]`): `[^,]+`
- Followed by a comma `,`
- Now give me 3 of those groups after each other `{3}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex to get the result

```js
const str = 'Hi, this, sentence, has, a, lot, of commas';
const m = str.match(/^(?:[^,]*,){2}([^,]*)/)[0];
console.log(m);
```